# How to switch user in AIX shell script?

Tags: db2, aix, su

I want to run a DB2 query from shell script. I have a user `db2inst1` that's required to execute DB2 statements. I am running an application that uses `root` user to run the shell script. HERE if I switch user to db2inst1. I can do the job.

Following is my scipt that runs perfect with `db2inst1`.

```
#!/bin/sh
db2 "connect to customerdb"
db2 "set schema = db2inst1"
db2 "insert into tbl_customer(name,occupation) values ('Alex','Admin')"
```

See it like a root has to run it. So root user will let the script to switch user first before executing db commands.

My app will invoke this shell script which will use `root` user.

How can I switch user in script? I am new to shell scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are running as `root`, you can use:

```
su dbinst1 -c './your_script arg1 arg2 ...'
```

Were you not running as `root`, life would be harder.

Comment: My app will invoke this shell script which uses root user. I want every thing to be in script. I tried: `su db2inst1 -c 'db2 CONNECT TO customerdb USER db2inst1 USING admin; db2 -c -i - w -td@ -f /u01/IBM/workspace/addcustomer.sql'` but I got `ksh: db2:  not found.`

Comment: The environment is probably not set correctly; in particular, `$PATH` may be (re)set to a default value which does not include where the `db2` command is installed.  You may need to set some other environment variables too.  This would be done inside the `yourscript` file — by whatever name you call it.  Or it will be written out in a massive, multi-line command, but it is usually neater to run a script.

Comment: Adding `su - dbinst1 -c` with every statement in script did the job. Now my script is: `su - db2inst1 -c 'db2 connect to customeradb user  db2inst1 using admin'
su - db2inst1 -c 'db2 -tvsf /u01/IBM/workspace/addcustomer.sql'`

Comment: I am not sure why you need to be root and then use `su` to execute a script as another user.  This makes things needlessly complex.

Why not just grant access INSERT into the table to the ID that is executing script (i.e. the ID that is running the app?